# How to migrate windows installation from two discs/partitions two one partition on one new disc without reinstalling?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, migration

I currently run a windows 10 installation on my pc using a SSD and a HDD. The HDD only contains a set of user space applications and data stuff. I would like to merge those partitions into one and migrate them to my new SSD.

The old SSD does not have enough space to be able to also take the userspace applications from the HDD while the new SSD has enough space.

How can this be done and will it be possible to merge the partitions without doing damage to the installed applications?

My first guess would be that I have to somehow migrate the system partition "C:" to the new SSD somehow and than hope that everything will still work and then somehow solve the migration of the "D:" partition containing further applications.

I also would like to move the boot-section/manager or whatever windows uses to make its system bootable to the new SSD.

Comment: Use software to image both partitions, use same software to restore images to new SSD.

Comment: Aren't there any system tools provided by the system itself? I am don't want to break stuff using some weird unknown software that does some magic. Are there problem when I would boot a linux system dd the disc and put it to the new disc then wipe the old and change the UUID of the new one to the old one? How do I take care of the bootmanager in windows? What could break? Is it possible to merge the program folder from the second disc to the new SSD without violate dependencies?

Comment: No, Windows has no native tools to do this. There are reliable tools like Macrium reflect Free.